# Java fullscreen mode breaks JPopupMenu. Still works, but doesn't render

Tags: java, swing, fullscreen, jpopupmenu

I have a JPopupMenu that appears when a user right clicks on the window (as per usual with popups). When you're out in the middle of the screen, there's never a problem, but when you're up against the right side of the screen or the bottom, the menu just doesn't show up when in fullscreen mode.

Oddly enough, if you do the subsequent left click - pretending that the menu is there (because it actually is) - it will still select the correct value as if the menu's vertical and / or horizontal positions had been adjusted to compensate for the edges of the screen.

Even more oddly, this only happens on certain machines for reasons I can't fathom. E.g., I have two PCs here at work, both running Win7; one of them exhibits the failure, the other does not. On the machine that *does* exhibit the failure, the Win7 VM I have in it also does, but the Ubuntu VM does not. Now, one thing I noticed was that on the machines that do exhibit the rendering problem, the title bar of the JFrame disappears once full screen mode is entered, whereas the others do not (i.e. they still show the close and minimize buttons, making it seem like fullscreen exclusive mode on those machines was little more than maximizing).

Here is a fully functioning example of the problem (assuming your machine is magically susceptible to it) (enter fullscreen to see the problem)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.xml.ws.Holder;


public class ExclusiveModePopup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Exclusive Popup test");
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final Holder<Boolean> isInFullScreen = new Holder<Boolean>(false);
        final Holder<String> lastSelected = new Holder<String>("");
        final JPanel pane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        pane.add(new JPanel() {

            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
                FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
                int fontHeight = fm.getMaxAscent();
                g.setColor(Color.green);
                g.drawOval(5, 5, 20, 20);
                g.drawString("Right click here to see normal", 5, 25 + fontHeight);
                if(!isInFullScreen.value){
                    g.drawOval(5, this.getHeight() - 30, 20, 20);
                    g.drawString("Right click here to see vertical adjustment",
                            5, this.getHeight() - 35);
                    g.drawOval(this.getWidth() - 30, 5, 20, 20);
                    String alongRight = "Right click here to see horizontal adjustment";
                    int strWidth = fm.charsWidth(alongRight.toCharArray(), 0, alongRight.length());
                    g.drawString(alongRight, this.getWidth() - 5 - strWidth, 25 + fontHeight);
                    g.drawOval(this.getWidth() - 30, this.getHeight() - 30, 20, 20);
                    alongRight = "Right click here to see both values adjusted";
                    strWidth = fm.charsWidth(alongRight.toCharArray(), 0, alongRight.length());
                    g.drawString(alongRight, this.getWidth() - 5 - strWidth, this.getHeight() - 35);
                } else {
                    g.setColor(Color.red);
                    g.drawOval(5, this.getHeight() - 30, 20, 20);
                    g.drawString("Right click here to see failure",
                            5, this.getHeight() - 35);
                    g.drawOval(this.getWidth() - 30, 5, 20, 20);
                    String alongRight = "Right click here to see more failure";
                    int strWidth = fm.charsWidth(alongRight.toCharArray(), 0, alongRight.length());
                    g.drawString(alongRight, this.getWidth() - 5 - strWidth, 25 + fontHeight);
                    g.drawOval(this.getWidth() - 30, this.getHeight() - 30, 20, 20);
                    alongRight = "Right click here to see yet some moar failure";
                    strWidth = fm.charsWidth(alongRight.toCharArray(), 0, alongRight.length());
                    g.drawString(alongRight, this.getWidth() - 5 - strWidth, this.getHeight() - 35);
                }
                g.setColor(Color.white);
                String lastSel = "Last selected value: " + lastSelected.value;
                int strWidth = fm.charsWidth(lastSel.toCharArray(), 0, lastSel.length());
                g.drawString(lastSel, this.getWidth() / 2 - strWidth / 2, this.getHeight() / 2);
            }
        }, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        final JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            final int j = i; 
            popup.add(new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction("Long name item number " + i){
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    lastSelected.value = "Item #" + j;
                    pane.repaint();
                }
            }));
        }
        pane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                if ((e.getModifiers() & MouseEvent.BUTTON3_MASK) == MouseEvent.BUTTON3_MASK) {
                    popup.show((Component) e.getSource(), e.getX(), e.getY());
                }
            }
        });
        final GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
        pane.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Toggle Fullscreen") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if (gd.isFullScreenSupported()) {
                    if (!isInFullScreen.value) {
                        gd.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
                        isInFullScreen.value = true;
                    } else {
                        gd.setFullScreenWindow(null);
                        isInFullScreen.value = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setContentPane(pane);
        Rectangle screenBounds = gd.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        Insets screenInsets = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(gd.getDefaultConfiguration());
        frame.setLocation(screenBounds.width - frame.getWidth() - screenInsets.right,
                screenBounds.height - frame.getHeight() - screenInsets.bottom);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Thoughts? Thanks in advance.